# Controller cannot reach Controller in other project because of constructor ASP:NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, constructor, dependencies

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to solve this problem for a week now.
I have a solution with two projects.
And when I start the porject the browser just says:
**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TSM_Programm.Data.TSMContext' while attempting to activate 'TSM_Programm.Controllers.ResourcesController'.**

The first part of the solution is my API-Layer that passes data to a user (currently via postman).
The second project is my Data Access Layer.
This Layer contains several Controllers, all of them using the same constructor, which is the following:

```
public TSMContext _context;

        public ResourcesController(TSMContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

The TSMContext Class is the following:

```
namespace TSM_Programm.Data
{
    public class TSMContext : DbContext
    {

        public TSMContext(DbContextOptions<TSMContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }


        public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }     
        public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResourceToParameter> ResourceToParameters { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    }
```

So far so god, but when I am trying to start the program the controllerof the API-Layer does not seem to be able to handle the constructor.

This is my API-Conrtoller:

```
namespace TSM_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class APIController : ControllerBase  //Base Class without View Support
    {


        //Troublemaker
        public ResourcesController _resources;
        public ParametersController _parameters;
        public ReservationsController _reservations;


        public APIController(ResourcesController resources, ParametersController parameters, ReservationsController reservations)
        {
            _resources = resources;
            _parameters = parameters;
            _reservations = reservations;
        }
        //Function to check if controller works
        //GET: api/API
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
           // ResourcesController controller = new ResourcesController();
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

The API-Controller was not able to use its own constructors, that's why I changed the Startup.cs.

```
namespace TSM_API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ResourcesController).Assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ParametersController).Assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ReservationsController).Assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(TSMContext).Assembly).AddControllersAsServices();


        }
```

I'm simply out of ideas on how to solve the problem, since I can't add the TSMContext class a service. 
Any idea how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have not registered your dbcontext as a dependency injection. Your issue might be due to `ResourceController` trying to access `_context` as a DI but it is not registered. To use the context as a dependency injection, register it in the `startup.cs` as following.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TSMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING")));

//If you have any services that should be used as DI, then they also must be registered as like this
    services.AddScoped<Interface, Class>(); //Interface refer to the service interface while class is the actual service you will use.
}
```

Comment: I worked! Thank you so much. I works fine now and I can use my Methods from the ResourcesController in my APIController. Just like I needed it. :)